# Why are quads not rendering with OpenTK 4.7.5 when similar code works with OpenTk 3.3.3?

Tags: c#, .net, opentk

The following code will not render the quads with .Net 6 and OpenTK 4.7.5, but (nearly) identical code works with .Net 4.8 and OpenTK 3.3.3.

(Triangles will render fine, but I would rather use quads, because they are just more easy to handle for my use case.)

.Net 6 with OpenTK 4.7.5

```
using OpenTK.Windowing.Common;
using OpenTK.Windowing.Desktop;
using OpenTK.Graphics.ES30;
using OpenTK.Mathematics;

using Game game = new(new GameWindowSettings(), NativeWindowSettings.Default);

game.Run();

public class Game : GameWindow
{
    public Game(GameWindowSettings gameWindowSettings, NativeWindowSettings nativeWindowSettings) : base(gameWindowSettings, nativeWindowSettings)
    { }

    private readonly Vector2[] _circleVertices =
    {
        new(-0.1f, -0.1f),
        new(-0.1f, 0.1f),
        new(0.1f, 0.1f),
        new(0.1f, -0.1f),

        new(0.2f, 0.2f),
        new(0.7f, 0.2f),
        new(0.7f, 0.7f),
        new(0.2f, 0.7f),
    };

    private int _vertexArrayObject;

    private Shader _shader;

    protected override unsafe void OnLoad()
    {
        base.OnLoad();

        GL.ClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);

        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, GL.GenBuffer());

        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, _circleVertices.Length * sizeof(Vector2), _circleVertices, BufferUsageHint.DynamicDraw);

        GL.BindVertexArray(_vertexArrayObject = GL.GenVertexArray());

        GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, sizeof(Vector2), 0);

        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        string vertexShader = @"
#version 450 core

layout (location = 0) in vec2 position;

uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0, 1.0);
}";

        string fragmentShader = @"
#version 450 core

out vec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
    fragColor = vec4(1);
}";

        _shader = new Shader(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    }

    protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnRenderFrame(e);

        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);

        GL.UseProgram(_shader.Handle);

        GL.BindVertexArray(_vertexArrayObject);

        GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Quads, 0, _circleVertices.Length);

        GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.LineStrip, 0, _circleVertices.Length);

        Context.SwapBuffers();
    }
}

public class Shader
{
    public readonly int Handle;

    public Shader(string vertexShader, string fragmentPath)
    {
        Handle = GL.CreateProgram();

        GL.AttachShader(Handle, Create(vertexShader, ShaderType.VertexShader));
        GL.AttachShader(Handle, Create(fragmentPath, ShaderType.FragmentShader));

        GL.LinkProgram(Handle);

        GL.GetProgram(Handle, GetProgramParameterName.LinkStatus, out int success);
        if (success == 0)
            Console.WriteLine(GL.GetProgramInfoLog(Handle));
    }

    private int Create(string shader, ShaderType type)
    {
        int reference = GL.CreateShader(type);
        GL.ShaderSource(reference, shader);
        GL.CompileShader(reference);

        GL.GetShader(reference, ShaderParameter.CompileStatus, out int success);
        if (success == 0)
            Console.WriteLine(GL.GetShaderInfoLog(reference));
        return reference;
    }
}
```

.Net 4.8 with OpenTK 3.3.3

```
using System;
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4;

namespace MVP_Error_net4
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using Game game = new(640, 360);
            game.Run(60);
        }
    }
}

public class Game : GameWindow
{
    public Game(int width, int height) : base(width, height) { }

    private readonly Vector2[] _circleVertices =
    {
        new(-0.1f, -0.1f),
        new(-0.1f, 0.1f),
        new(0.1f, 0.1f),
        new(0.1f, -0.1f),

        new(0.2f, 0.2f),
        new(0.7f, 0.2f),
        new(0.7f, 0.7f),
        new(0.2f, 0.7f),
    };

    private int _vertexArrayObject;

    private Shader _shader;

    protected override unsafe void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        GL.ClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);

        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, GL.GenBuffer());

        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, _circleVertices.Length * sizeof(Vector2), _circleVertices, BufferUsageHint.DynamicDraw);

        GL.BindVertexArray(_vertexArrayObject = GL.GenVertexArray());

        GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, sizeof(Vector2), 0);

        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        string vertexShader = @"
#version 450 core

layout (location = 0) in vec2 position;

uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0, 1.0);
}";

        string fragmentShader = @"
#version 450 core

out vec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
    fragColor = vec4(1);
}";

        _shader = new Shader(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    }

    protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnRenderFrame(e);

        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);

        GL.UseProgram(_shader.Handle);

        GL.BindVertexArray(_vertexArrayObject);

        GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Quads, 0, _circleVertices.Length);

        GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.LineStrip, 0, _circleVertices.Length);

        Context.SwapBuffers();
    }
}

public class Shader
{
    public readonly int Handle;

    public Shader(string vertexShader, string fragmentPath)
    {
        Handle = GL.CreateProgram();

        GL.AttachShader(Handle, Create(vertexShader, ShaderType.VertexShader));
        GL.AttachShader(Handle, Create(fragmentPath, ShaderType.FragmentShader));

        GL.LinkProgram(Handle);

        GL.GetProgram(Handle, GetProgramParameterName.LinkStatus, out int success);
        if (success == 0)
            Console.WriteLine(GL.GetProgramInfoLog(Handle));
    }

    private int Create(string shader, ShaderType type)
    {
        int reference = GL.CreateShader(type);
        GL.ShaderSource(reference, shader);
        GL.CompileShader(reference);

        GL.GetShader(reference, ShaderParameter.CompileStatus, out int success);
        if (success == 0)
            Console.WriteLine(GL.GetShaderInfoLog(reference));
        return reference;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with the code is that `PrimitiveType.Quads` is not supported in OpenGL 3.0 and above, which is used by OpenTK 4.7.5. Instead, use `PrimitiveType.Triangles` and specify the indices of the vertices that make up each quad. Another option would be to use a geometry shader to convert the input triangles into quads.